# Correct/preferred way to access staticmethod from within class instance

Tags: python, class, oop, static-methods

When accessing a static method from a regular instance method in a Python class, there are 2 different options which both seem to work - accessing via the `self` object, and accessing via the class name itself, e.g.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    @staticmethod
    def div_2(x: int):
        return x / 2

    def option_1(self):
        return Foo.div_2(self.x)

    def option_2(self):
        return self.div_2(self.x)
```

Is there any reason for preferring one way over the other?

Comment: The way I do this is to use self.div_2 from within another method and Foo.div_2 from outside the class.

Answer (score 3):

The two do different things: `Foo.div_2` calls the method of `Foo`; instead `self.div_2` may call a different method if `self` if an instance of a class derived from `Foo`:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    @staticmethod
    def div_2(x: int):
        return x * 2

b = Bar(12)
print(b.option_1()) # prints 6.0
print(b.option_2()) # prints 24
```

Comment: Thanks that's an interesting consideration I hadn't thought of.